# Enable FullTextSearch in Silverstripe 4

Tags: full-text-search, config, silverstripe-4, schema.yml

In Silverstripe 4 FulltextSearchable::enable(); fails in _config.php
Does anyone know how to get this working again so that $SearchForm works in templates?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific please? You'll need to provide a clear description of the problem as well as steps to reproduce and expected results

Answer (score 1):

Use 

`\SilverStripe\ORM\Search\FulltextSearchable::enable();`

in _config.php not

`FulltextSearchable::enable();`