# Silverstripe 4 - How do you enable FullTextSearchable and $SearchForm?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Upgrading site from 3 to 4. Existing code makes use of FullTextSearchable as per [this guide](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/tutorials/site_search/) that exists for 3, but not for 4. Google only results in unanswered questions of the same nature. Except for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54068647/enable-fulltextsearch-in-silverstripe-4), which doesn't help. But I do find [this guide](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/search/fulltextsearch/) for SS4, which is not geared towards the same topic really, but somewhat helpful.

Here is my code:

_config.php

```
\SilverStripe\ORM\Search\FulltextSearchable::enable();
```

Page.php

```
use SilverStripe\ORM\Connect\MySQLSchemaManager;

private static $create_table_options = [
    MySQLSchemaManager::ID => 'ENGINE=MyISAM'
];
```

Page.ss

```
$SearchForm
```

Expected: Standard search form is displayed

Actual: Nothing is displayed

I went as far as to hard code the form from the existing site onto the template to see if the search function itself works:

Page.ss

```
<form id="SearchForm_SearchForm" action="/home/SearchForm" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <p id="SearchForm_SearchForm_error" class="message " style="display: none"></p>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="Search" value="Search" class="text nolabel" id="SearchForm_SearchForm_Search">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="action_results" value="Go" class="action" id="SearchForm_SearchForm_action_results">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Expected: Search results page displays with relevant search results for the entered term

Actual: 404 page not found